# Jackson Xml duplicate Tag name

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jackson-databind

I'm generating xml using jackson xml, My POJO class for jackson xml generation as below:

```
public class data { 

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="Element") 
    Element element = new Element();  

}
```

```
public class Element {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="element1")
    private List<String> element1;
    public List<String> getElement1() {
        return element1;
    }    
    public void setElement1(List<String> element1) {
        this.element1 = element1;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting an output like:

```
<Element>
  <element1></element1>
  <element1></element1>
  <element1></element1>
</Element>
```

but I'm getting:

```
<Element>
 <element1>
   <element1></element1>
   <element1></element1>
   <element1></element1>
 <element1>
</Element>
```

how to solve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add [JacksonXmlElementWrapper](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html)

```
 @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)   
 @JacksonXmlProperty(localName="element1")
    private List<String> element1;
```

> Annotation that is similar to JAXB javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper, to indicate wrapper element to use (if any) for Collection types (arrays, java.util.Collection). If defined, a separate container (wrapper) element is used; if not, entries are written without wrapping.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable collection elements duplication globally (to avoid repeating/using annotation on multiple places). Just create your mapper with setting `defaultUseWrapper(false)`:

```
mapper = XmlMapper.builder().defaultUseWrapper(false).build();
```